# Ajax doesn't work propperly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a problem with my ajax displaying the response in an alert.

I use jquery and ajax. The javascript contains a normal GET-Request. The ajax doesn't go to the .done function. The website displays the second alert:

> alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");

But in the browser it displays in the console. I'm using firefox + a Plug-in for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/reviews/). I don't think the plugin is the proplem because without the plugin it's also working.

So here is my **html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Peyer E1 9.2 Auswahl</title>
        <script src="clearcache.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="data()">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my **Javascript:**

```
function data() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url",
        dataType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Success.");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to diagnose any issues there?

Comment: How are you defining URL in your ajax call? At the moment It's just a string which would explain the failed error

Comment: I replaced the URL @kawnah

Comment: what are you doing with the data ? have you a php file with process data ? have you tried with post medthod ?

Comment: What about setting dataType to JSONP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: If it's hitting the fail callback then it failed.  Open the Url in your browser and you should see at least a vague indication of a server error.

Comment: @kawnah setting it to jsonp doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Doggo must be a bad URL then - do what archer is saying and just open it directly in browser and see what's going on

Comment: But @Archer I see the expected output in the console. But the alert says something else.

Comment: What happens when you go to the Url in your browser?

Comment: @kawnah the fact JSONP failed does nothing to prove the URL is wrong. JSONP is not a magic 'fix all'. It requires the server response to be in a certain format explicitly for cross-domain requests, which is highly unlikely to be used in this case.

Comment: @Archer without athentication it says forbidden obv.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I didn't say it was a magic fix all, but if the data is in a different format then it would cause problems. It was worth asking. And I'm not the only one that suggested a bad URL - in fact the original suggestion has 2 upvotes...

Comment: When you say "I see the expected output in the console", what do you see exactly?  The request *__is__* failing, otherwise it would not be executing the code in the fail handler.

Comment: it may be that the server doesn't accept Authorization from javascript

Comment: And have you tried dataType: "json" ?

Comment: I see excactly the GET-Request with the Code 200. I see the json which i want.

Comment: In that case it's most likely failing whilst trying to parse the response. 
 Change datatype to json, rather than "application/json", which is not a valid data type (you're confusing it with a content-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a 200 result from the Ajax request then it's failing when it's attempting to parse the response.

Change the `dataType` value in the Ajax request to "json".  It's currently "application/json", which is not a valid data type...

```
function data() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "url",
        dataType: "json",    //  make sure this is correct
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Success.");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
    });
}
```